# online error of "The 'Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am creating my website using my visual studio and Microsoft access as to create my database. in my local server and my own PC this web  compile and run perfectly , but whenever I try to upload my web on the server and then run the part of my website that the web try to get access to the database I get the following error :

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I've searched the internet and they all said it's because you are running on 64 bit windows and its' configs are for win 32 bit.

I have windows XP 32 bit and it works perfectly on my PC, but I think it's because of the servers local machines that are running on windows 64 bit (maybe).
but the problem is I don't know what to do here. I don't know what to do. and all the internet solutions were for offline console programs, not the web services.

Answer (score 0):

Try by installing this?: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

OR

1. Open the IIS 7.5 manager and select the application pool corresponding to your web application.
2. Right click the application pool and select ‘Advanced settings’.
3. Select the field ‘Enable 32-bit applications’ and change it to 'true'.
4. Restart your application pool and access your application to fix the error you saw.

Greatz

Comment: thnx but I've installed the 32 bit version of software you told to install. what now? :\ how can a software that is installed on my computer do anything with the server?

Comment: Have you tried to test the connection again? Cause I had a similar problem a while ago and this fixed it for me.. And just to make sure.. try to install it on both systems.. and try then

Answer (score 0):

The simplest workaround is to change the Target Platform of your application through Visual Studio menu

In Project explorer:

```
 Solution (Right-Click) -> Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform -> x86
```

If the `x86` option is not already there, then select NEW, name it `x86`, Copy Settings from `AnyCPU` and check Create new project platforms